# How to use Enumeration as the only Possible Error Values?

Tags: rust

Here's the error type that I wrote:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct AppErr {
    pub code: String,
    pub message: String,
}
```

I want AppErr to only have several possible values, so I use Enumeration

```
pub enum AppErrEnum {
    IncompatibleOS,
    FileNotFound,
    InvalidInput,
    UnknownErr,
}
```

I need to somehow convert `AppErrEnum` into `AppErr` type.
So I use a function (`convert_err()`) such as this:

```
fn convert_err(val: AppErrEnum) -> AppErr {
    match val {
        AppErrEnum::IncompatibleOS => AppErr {
            code: String::from("INCOMPATIBLE_OS"),
            message: String::from("Sistem Operasi tidak didukung. Hanya support Windows Client."),
        },
        
        AppErrEnum::UnknownErr => AppErr {
            code: String::from("UNKNOWN_ERR"),
            message: String::from("Terjadi kesalahan yang tidak diketahui."),
        },

        // ..... other enum values here

    }
}
```

and I had to call the `convert_err()` in every instance of error

```
Err(convert_err(AppErrEnum::IncompatibleOS))
```

I found that this method is kinda ugly. I had to explicitly export the `convert_err` function and call it almost on every file.

Is there any way to automatically convert this enum type into `AppErr` so I can throw an error like this ? This is much simpler and easier to read for me:

```
Err(AppErrEnum::IncompatibleOS)
```

Comment: I'm curious, why are you trying to convert your errors like this? If you're just trying to have a nice message for your errors, [how about](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bc6842c409e03500bf4d42493eda53e5) implementing `std::error::Error`. Or maybe look into things like [thiserror](https://docs.rs/thiserror/latest/thiserror/).

Comment: @Caesar: since I'm new to Rust. Recently migrated from Javascript. Error handling with classes such as is new for me. I think it will be great to have a list of all possible errors in one place/file. `thiserror` seems neat!, Thank you for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `std::convert::From` trait for implicit conversion

```rust
impl From<AppErrEnum> for AppErr {
    fn from(error: AppErrEnum) -> Self {
        match val {
            AppErrEnum::IncompatibleOS => AppErr {
                code: String::from("INCOMPATIBLE_OS"),
                message: String::from("Sistem Operasi tidak didukung. Hanya support Windows Client."),
            },
            
            AppErrEnum::UnknownErr => AppErr {
                code: String::from("UNKNOWN_ERR"),
                message: String::from("Terjadi kesalahan yang tidak diketahui."),
            },

            // ..... other enum values here

        }
    }
}
```

This can then be used as follows:

```rust
fn some_fn() -> Result<u32, AppErrEnum> { ... }

fn another_fn() -> Result<u32, AppErr> {
    some_fn()?
}
```

Comment: Just to emphasize, it's the `?` in the call that's doing all of the magic. `?` will happily call `From` as part of its error-handling, so it can be used to discreetly convert between error types. In fact, `?` will allow types other than `Result` as well, using the [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait, but that feature is less used, since `Result` is good enough for almost any use case.